# Custom Rewrite Tag Structure

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I am pondering over this intriguing question and I have yet to find an answer. I need to add my own **Custom [Structure Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags)** for my `cpt`s.

Extract fromt he link above:

> **%year%**
>   The year of the post, four digits, for example 2004
>
> **%monthnum%**
>   Month of the year, for example 05
>
> **%day%**
>   Day of the month, for example 28

In my case I do not need the date the post has been published. For each post that belongs to certain CPTs (events, contests, promotions) I need the start date of the event/contest/promotion.

For each post that belong to those cpts I have stored a **DATETIME** post meta that I wish to be used in the formation of the CPTs permalink like so:

`site.com/events/%eventyear%/%eventmonth%/%eventday%/%postname%/`

That will turn into:

`site.com/events/2015/3/11/tca-annual-convention/`

Where `2015` and `3` and `11` are information parsed out of `e_startdatetime` (2015-03-11 20:00:00).

If the post meta is not set, then the date is that of the UNIX Epoch because 0.

Anybody has any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167339/4771).

Comment: @Milo Thank you! All I had to do was use `post_type_link` instead of `post_link`. Thanks!