# taxonomy term in URL slug won't forward to the correct term for custom post like it does for default categories/normal posts

Tags: url-rewriting, taxonomy, redirect, urls, slug

so I notice when you type the URL of a post with a category (eg category5/post), it will automatically forward to the correct category in the URL (eg category5 changes to category1) if the category doesn't match the post.

I can't seem to be able to do this with taxonomies and custom post types.

Using WP_Debug plugin I tried to see if it was something to do with the request itself.

```
Request:
argha/what/test-2

Query String:
name=test-2&category_name=argha%2Fwhat

Matched Rewrite Rule:
(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$

Matched Rewrite Query:
category_name=argha%2Fwhat&name=test-2&page=
```

No problem there. it redirects to this rewrite query no matter what I type for the category.
Here is the one for my taxonomies and custom post types.

```
Request:
my/technology/tablets/ipad

Query String:
name=ipad&post_type=my&mycategory=technology%2Ftablets

Matched Rewrite Rule:
my/(.+?)/(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$

Matched Rewrite Query:
mycategory=technology%2Ftablets&post_type=my&name=ipad
```

It's practically identical aside from the fact I had to use a different rewrite rule since the default one didn't work properly (i couldn't view the taxonomy archive pages).. 
see below. The rest of the site functions perfectly with it!

```
     $newRules['my/(.+?)/(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?mycategory=$matches[1]%2F$matches[2]&post_type=my&name=$matches[3]';
    $newRules['my/(.+)/?$']           = 'index.php?mycategory=$matches[1]';
```

EDIT:

Registering my custom post type and taxonomy, I used these values for args.

```
                       'public' => true,
                       'publicly_queryable' => true,
                       'show_ui' => true,
                       'query_var' => true,
                       'rewrite' => array(
                            'slug' => 'my/%mycategory%',
                            'with_front' => true,
                           'pages' => true
                        ),
                       'capability_type' => 'post',

                       'hierarchical' => true,
```

and taxonomy

```
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'with_front' => true,

        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'my',
            'with_front' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true
```

In addition to the rewrite rules, I utilised this code (I'm not sure how relevant all this code is.)

```
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'my')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'mycategory'))
    {
    $link = str_replace('%mycategory%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'mycategory', false, '/', true), $link);
}
return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);


function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {
$chain = '';
$parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
    return $parent;
}

if ($nicename)
    $name = $parent -> slug;
else
    $name = $parent -> name;

if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {
    $visited[] = $parent -> parent;
    $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);

}

if ($link) {

} else
    $chain .= $name . $separator;
return $chain;
}

function restrict_things_by_category() {
global $typenow;
$post_type = 'my';
$taxonomy = 'mycategory';
if ($typenow == $post_type) {
    $selected = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
    $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
    wp_dropdown_categories(array(
        'show_option_all' => __("Show All {$info_taxonomy->label}"),
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'name' => $taxonomy,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'selected' => $selected,
        'show_count' => true,
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));
};
}

add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'restrict_things_by_category');

function convert_id_to_term_in_query($query) {
global $pagenow;
$post_type = 'my';
$taxonomy = 'mycategory';
$q_vars = &$query->query_vars;
if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($q_vars['post_type']) && $q_vars['post_type'] == $post_type && isset($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && is_numeric($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && $q_vars[$taxonomy] != 0) {
    $term = get_term_by('id', $q_vars[$taxonomy], $taxonomy);
    $q_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
}
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'convert_id_to_term_in_query');
```

Please help because this is driving me nuts, and the purpose of the site is for users to submit content... it's uncategorised at first but if they share it and it becomes categorised later it needs to forward to the correct URL... plus I'm thinking this might hurt SEO as well?

This code was originally used so I could have hierarchical URLs generated.
eg

parent term (example.com/my/parent/) shows content all related to parent term incl. all child terms
child term (example.com/my/parent/child) shows content only within that child term
custom post (example.com/my/parent/child/post/) is the post, and any new created post with the child term 'checked' will generate this URL. else it will just generate (example.com/my/%mycategory%/post) which of course results in a 404...

Here's code from previous answer that still doesn't seem to work - it doesn't seem to make any changes for wp_query either, though if I use 'key' for the array() it detects that.. but I don't think that's what I'm after.

```
 function wpd_single_cpt_queries( $query ){
   if( $query->is_singular()
     && $query->is_main_query()
     && isset( $query->query_vars['mycategory'] ) ){
     $tax_query = array(
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'mycategory',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $query->query_vars['mycategory']


         )
     );
     $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
  }
  }

   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_single_cpt_queries' );
```

Comment: Rewrite rules only handle incoming requests, show us the code you use to generate the URLs for your CPT. You also need to enforce the correct taxonomy term in your query for these posts. [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167339/4771) might help you understand what parts are missing.

Comment: OK, will edit the question accordingly. I have posted a similar question before using a guest account but could not follow it up.

Comment: The likely issue is that you have hierarchical terms, you need a rewrite rule for each level of hierarchy. query var values like `technology%2Ftablets` will not work.

Comment: I don't understand, do I have to edit my rewrite rules completley ($newrules) or the function labelled wpd_single_cpt_queries, or both?

Comment: I've changed it to `$newRules['my/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/?$'] = 'index.php?mycategory=$matches[1]&mycategory=$matches[2]&my=$matches[3]';`  but nothing at all has changed. Like I said the rest of the site works fine but having a url such as "FAKECATEGORY/FAKECATEGORY/ipad" will show the same ipad page

Comment: I just want it to redirect to the correct and matching taxonomy in the URL for the post-type like the default category/post does...

Comment: So have I set up the rewrite rules correctly here? I've been deactivating plugins left right and centre and removed anything that I think might clash, or even things that aren't unrelated but nothing works! I can't find anybody else with the same problem either and it's driving me nuts. Why do normal categories automatically do this without any additional code but these taxonomies don't? If this is sorted then I shouldn't really have any further issues for the site.

Comment: (I'm guessing this doesn't usually happen on any other site but I can't figure out what I could have done wrong :\ )

Comment: sorry, I haven't tried your code to see what might be the issue. Basically, when a request is a 404, WordPress tries to figure out what you might be requesting by doing a LIKE query on the title. For whatever reason, your query isn't generating a 404, possibly due to how query vars are set, or if it is generating a 404, incorrect query vars make WordPress unable to guess what type of object you want. You need to inspect query vars and make sure they are the correct values for successfully restricting the query to the combined title/tax terms.

Comment: OK, sorry for the impatience haha - it is stressing me out a bit :P Thanks for the info, I'll see what I can do I reckon.

Comment: Nope, I still don't understand. Everything seems to match the default WP functionality.  I honestly have no idea what i could be doing wrong. If Wordpress can fetch the urls automatically I don't get why I can't get it to redirect to the url it auto-fetches :(

Comment: furthermore looks like even taxonomy archive pages are borked.... ie 'blahblah/tablets' returns tablets.. so the parent taxonomy is irrelevant. arghh!!!